# Try catch is behaving wierd in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

I was learning the example and I am not a

```cpp
#include <windows.h> // for EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

#include <excpt.h>

int filter(unsigned int code, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ep) {

    puts("in filter.");

    if (code == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION) {

        puts("caught AV as expected.");

        return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;

    }

    else {

        puts("didn't catch AV, unexpected.");

        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;

    };

}

int main()

{

    int* p = 0x00000000;   // pointer to NULL

    puts("hello");

    __try {

        puts("in try");

        __try {

            puts("in try");

            *p = 13;    // causes an access violation exception;

        }
        __finally {

            puts("in finally. termination: ");

            puts(AbnormalTermination() ? "\tabnormal" : "\tnormal");

        }

    }
    __except (filter(GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation())) {

        puts("in except");

    }

    puts("world");

}
```

Output of program is:

```
hello
in try
in try
in filter.
caught AV as expected.
in finally. termination:
        abnormal
in except
world
```

I am confused in why it goes to filter first and then to finally and then prints "in except".
Isn't that true if it goes to __except then it should complete the execution.

Comment: Use c++ standard syntax if asking for c++ code please, otherwise put another tag there.

Comment: Not sure you can nest two `__try` in the same function. Worth checking.

Comment: Thank you guys.. just by reading __try definition I thought it is analogous with try catch

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It looks like beginner's code, but this example is copied verbatim from MSDN's documentation.

Comment: @NickyC: SEH has specific properties, that allows *"applications to gain control when events that normally terminate program execution occur."* C++ exception handling does not offer this, and when you need to use SEH you need to use SEH. Microsoft doesn't recommend to use C++ exception handling for someting, C++ exception cannot do. Specifically in this example, C++ exception handling will not catch the access violation (writing to a `nullptr`).

Comment: please tag according to which compiler you are using, since you are using compiler-specific keywords

Comment: @M.M. These keywords are more platform-specific than compiler-specific. At one time they were documented as part of the Windows API (!), but without the internals documented. As I recall there was some special deal with Borland to let Borland have inside knowledge so they could provide the same keywords in their compiler.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf well ok, but some sort of tag would still be good. ("winapi" doesn't imply SEH keywords, since winapi functions are perfectly usable from non-SEH compilers)

Comment: @M.M. "mostly" perfectly usable. Just like C++ iostreams can throw C++ excpetions if so configured, so, as I recall, some of the Windows heap functions can throw SEH exceptions, if so configured. I don't understand how engineers can create such a mess. It must be the managers! ;-p

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Attempted vendor lockin. MS has backed away from that now but they were big on it in the 90s.

Comment: SEH is not attempted vendor lock-in. The operating system needed an exception-handling mechanism that didn't have anything to do with C++. For one thing, C++ exceptions hadn't been invented yet. For another, the OS wasn't written in C++. For a third, the C++ exception handling mechanism requires run-time support, which obviously requires the OS or somebody to write the code. Windows uses SEH. It is much more powerful than the exception handling defined by the C++ spec, and can catch errors that can't be caught with regular try/catch. The FUD is not constructive.

Comment: @M.M: I'm afraid, you come across as rather clueless. SEH is a system service, that allows exceptions to be implemented into any programming language (C++, Delphi, C#, etc.). It is a clean interface, that supports synchronous and asynchronous exception handling and stack unwinding, and can be used by any language vendor. I have no idea, how you interpret openness to be some sort of *"lock-in"*. Let's just keep it at that: You have not the slightest clue, what you are talking about. Just don't spread your uninformed opinions, please.

Comment: @IInspectable well, you come across as a MS shill. Nice meeting you

Comment: @M.M: At the very least, I do understand the technology I'm commenting on. You... not so. Get back to your books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't standard C++ exceptions but Microsoft's own language extensions.

If you had continued on from the page where you found that example to read [the documentation for `try-finally`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xtt5hxz.aspx), you would have found this:

> If a handler is found, any and all __finally blocks are executed and execution resumes in the handler.

This isn't surprising - in languages that have these constructs, the `finally` block is always executed (that's the purpose of it).
It's just that normally, the programmer has no runtime control over where or if the exception gets caught, so you can't interrupt the processing to look behind the scenes as you did with `filter`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: *"Even Microsoft recommends that you not use these in C++."* - Microsoft doesn't recommend to use C++ exception handling for situations, where C++ exception handling cannot be used. Specifically, catching access violations (due to dereferencing and writing to a `nullptr`, for example), necessitates the use of SEH. C++ exception handling cannot be used in the OP's code.

Comment: The surprising thing is that the filter for outer `__try` is executed before the `__finally` of the inner `__try`. And I agree with @IInspectable that the comment about how screwdrivers should preferably be used to drive in nails, is at best misleading.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm removing that sentence because it's beside the point.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I believe that is just how SEH works. When an exception is raised, the system first walks up the exception filters to find one, that is interested in handling this specific exception (so-called *first-chance exception*), and when found, it goes back to the faulting code and starts to unwind the stack. The `__finally` clause is executed immediately after the stack for the current frame has been unwound.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks, I think that's worthy of being an answer (at least if it can be supported by docs). That SEH is different from the clear nesting of effects of C++ exception handling. The 2 pass thing. I wonder if there is difference between 32-bit and 64-bit here. I haven't kept up to date.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The only (significant) difference between 32-bit and 64-bit SEH is the use of table-based exception handling for the latter. With 32-bit code, the compiler emits code for each `__try`/`__except` statement to set up a stack-based exception frame. For 64-bit SEH, the compiler generates tables that are used to look up exception filters, given the current instruction pointer. This implies, that 64-bit code exhibits truly zero-overhead for the non-throwing case (ignoring the increase in executable image size). True for both SEH and C++ exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

In the micorosoft site the following statement is written :

> Exiting a try-finally statement using the longjmp run-time function is considered abnormal termination. It is illegal to jump into a __try statement, but legal to jump out of one. All __finally statements that are active between the point of departure (normal termination of the __try block) and the destination (the __except block that handles the exception) must be run. This is called a local unwind.

It clearly mention that first try block is executed then _except and then at last before exiting try block it executes finally block.

Refer.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xtt5hxz.aspx